# How to use mutex correctly as parameter for a memberfunction in a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, mutex

My Problem is that I dont know how to properly use the mutex. I understand how it works theoretically but I don´t know why it doesnt work in my code.I thought if I use a mutex on a var it will be blocked until it gets unlocked. Nevertheless it seems I still have a data race.

I tried to define a class mutex and a mutex in the main which I pass by reference. Somehow nothing of this works.

```
class test {
public:
    void dosmth(std::mutex &a);
    int getT(){return t;};

private:
    int t = 0;
};


void test::dosmth(std::mutex &a) {
    for(;;){
        a.lock();
        t++;
        if(t==1000){
            t=0;
        }
        a.unlock();
    }
}

int main() {
    test te;
    std::mutex help;
    std::thread t(&test::dosmth, std::addressof(te), std::ref(help));
    for(;;){
        for (int i = 0; i <te.getT() ; ++i) {
            std::cout<<te.getT()<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The result just should be that I get some output so I will now it works.

Comment: I don't understand what is this program supposed to do? What are you trying to synchronize access to?

Comment: @PeterT nothing I just wrote it to better understand mutex and how to avoid data race

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mutex can only guarantee mutual exclusion if said mutex is used to regulate entry to *all* [critical sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) of code where a given object would be accessed concurrently. In your case, you have your second thread modify the value of the object `te.t` while your main thread is reading the value of the same object. Only one thread, however, is using a mutex to protect the access to `te.t`. The object `te.t` is not atomic. Therefore, you have a data race and, thus, undefined behavior [[intro.races]/21](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#21).

You have to also lock and unlock the mutex in your `for(;;)` loop in main, e.g.:

```
    for(;;){
        help.lock();
        for (int i = 0; i <te.getT() ; ++i) {
            std::cout<<te.getT()<<std::endl;
        }
        help.unlock();
    }
```

or better, using [std::lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard):

```
    for(;;){
        std::lock_guard lock(help);
        for (int i = 0; i <te.getT() ; ++i) {
            std::cout<<te.getT()<<std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep it works. I thought `lock_guard` is "used" when the descriptor is called. Is it then also the case for a repition in the for loop, I mean how does it works in loops?

Comment: @MaestroD `lock` is a local variable of type `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` inside the block of the loop. It will be constructed every time control flow comes across its definition and destructed every time control flow exits the block after it was constructed. In other words: it will be constructed at the beginning and destructed at the end of every iteration of the loop…

Answer (score 2):

As Michael mentioned, you should synchronise the reader and writer to avoid undefined behaviour. Instead of passing the `mutex` as an argument, a common pattern is to make the `mutex` a member of the object (`te`), lock and unlock every time (prefer `lock_gaurd` instead of manually locking and unlocking) you enter a member function (that modifies internal state of the object). Here is some pseudo-code:

```
class Foo{
    std::mutex m; // reader and writer are sync'ed on the same mutex
    int data_to_sync;
public:
    int read(){
        lock_gaurd<mutex> lg(m); //RAII lock
        return data_to_sync;
        //automagically released upon exit
    }
    void write(){
        lock_gaurd<mutex> lg(m);
        data_to_sync++;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use it this way next time :D

Answer (score 1):

> I thought if I use a mutex on a var...

You don't use a mutex "on a var."  Locking a mutex prevents other threads from locking the same mutex at the same time, but it does *not* stop other threads from accessing any particular variable(s).

If you want to use a mutex to protect a variable (or more typically, several variables) from being accessed by more than one thread at the same time, then it's *up to you* to ensure that you do not write *any* code that accesses the variables without locking the mutex first.